# Error al seleccionar un valor que empieza por un carácter determinado

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe de 3085 filas x 130 columnas, las cuales me centro en la primera columna que es el NHC (identificador del paciente) y las columnas D1 D2,D3 hasta la D20.

Como este es un ejemplo pondré tres filas de cuatro columnas

```
     NHC          D1             D2          D3
      52      J45.909         UY.852      IR.400
     1523     IOP.856         J45.30       IO443
     85       AB.93           AY808        UO.900
```

Los códigos que hay inscritos en cada columna (D1,D2,D3)
indican diferentes afecciones del paciente.
Si aparece un carácter en algunas de las columnas D1-D3 que empice por "J45." indica que el paciente es asmático.
Me gustaría que se obtiese un output como este:

```
    NHC      Asmático
     52          1
    1523         1   
     85          0
```

Para ello he construido el código para seleccionar aquellas NHC que incluyen un código determinado.

```
   Asthma<-array(0,dim(todo_junto_df)[1])
   for (i in 1:dim(todo_junto_df1)[1]) {
     if(any(which(todo_junto_df[i,]=="J45.901" | todo_junto_df[i,]=="J45.909" |        todo_junto_df[i,]=="J45.20" | todo_junto_df[i,]=="J45.30"| todo_junto_df[i,]=="J45.50"))) {
       Asthma[i]<-1
     }
   }
```

Sin embargo me gustaría saber si se podría seleccionar sin necesidad de poner todos los números que indican diferentes tipos de asma: J45.30, J45.909.
Es decir solo que seleccione aquellas que empiezan por J45. Para ello he usado la función:
start_with

```
   for (i in 1:dim(todo_junto_df1)[1]) {
      if(any(starts_with(todo_junto_df[i,]=="J45"))) {
        Asthma[i]<-1
      }
      }
   Error: `match` must be a character vector of non empty strings.
```

No se como solucionar este problema.

¿Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra forma interesante de resolverlo podría ser, generando la matriz de ocurrencias

```
mat <- as.matrix(todo_junto_df1[,-1])
encontrados <- matrix(grepl("^J45", mat), ncol = ncol(mat))
encontrados

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Lo cual te está diciendo exactamente en qué "celda" hemos encontrado el patrón, si luego quisieras seleccionar por fila:

```
todo_junto_df1[rowSums(encontrados) > 0,]

   NHC Código_1 Código_2 Código_3
1   52  J45.909   UY.852   IR.400
2 1523  IOP.856   J45.30    IO443
```

También, según tú última edición, puedes generar un nuevo `data.frame`

```
data.frame(NHC = todo_junto_df1$NHC, Asmático=as.integer(rowSums(encontrados) > 0))

   NHC Asmático
1   52        1
2 1523        1
3   85        0
```

Comment: he intentado ejecutar tu script y me devuelve este error: Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Comment: Fijate que en mi ejemplo el data.frame lo llamé `df` creo que el tuyo es `todo_junto_df1`, casi seguro es eso.

Comment: Efectivamente, sin duda alguna el código ha funcionado y de una forma más elegante de la que yo tenía. Muchas gracias Patricio

Answer (score 3):

En un comentario se aclara que lo buscado era un filtrado, no una selección. En ese caso:

```
as.numeric(apply(sapply(todo_junto_df, function (x) grepl("^J45", x)), 1, any))
```

> Respuesta anterior

No termino de entender la pregunta. Por el resultado que obtengo usando el código del primer bloque interpreto que quieres obtener un vector tan largo como columnas `Código_*` tienes en el data.frame, con el valor `1` si la columna tiene el patrón `J45` y `0` si no lo tiene.

En ese caso

```
as.numeric(
  sapply(todo_junto_df[-1], 
         function(x) any(grep("^J45", x)))
  )

[1] 1 1 0
```

Con R base. El `sapply()` se encarga de pasar un función por cada elemento de una lista (en este caso, cada columna de un data frame) y regresar el output simplificado, en este caso como un vector lógico.

La función que pasa es `grep` con el patrón regular `"^J45"` (el `^`  es para que busque al principio de una línea).

Si lo encuentra regresará `TRUE`. Como `grep` regresa un vector es necesario convertirlo es un valor único. Eso hace `any`: si en un vector hay al menos un valor `TRUE` regresa un único valor `TRUE`.

`sapply` regresará un vector lógica, con `as.numeric` se lo convierte en un vector numérico siguiendo la regla `TRUE = 1` y `FALSE = 0`.

Tu segundo bloque de código no funciona porque usas la función `starts_with`, que funciona solamente para seleccionar columnas por nombre. Selecciona si el nombre comienza con, no mira el "contenido" de la columna.

Se puede hacer algo parecido usando `purrr`

```
todo_junto_df %>% 
  map_int(~any(str_detect(.x, "^J45")))
```

Si lo que te interesa es hacer directamente el subset puedes usar

```
todo_junto_df %>% select_if(str_detect(., "J45"))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @mpaladino. En primer lugar siento no poder exponer el dataframe entero ya que tiene un tamaño descomonal (3825x130 variables). No obstante he metido la funciones que me sugeriste y no me funciona:  

Asthma<-array(0,dim(todo_junto_df)[1])
for (i in 1:dim(todo_junto_df1)[1]) {
  if(any(grep(todo_junto_df[i,]=="J45.",todo_junto_df1[17:36] ))) {
    Asthma[i]<-1
  }
}
Lo que quiero que seleccione en vez de por J45.XXXX solamente por J45 ya que todas las que me interesan empiezan así

Comment: también he utilizado la función contains y no lo selecciona

Comment: Tanto `starts_with` como `contains` "miran" a los nombres de las columnas, no al contenido. Entiendo que el `J45` que buscas está en las columnas, no en los nombres. Por eso te sugiero usar `grep` o `str_detect`. Quezás valga la pena que revises con cuidado la documentación de ambas funciones, en el código que pones en el 1er comentario `grep` está mal usada. PD: ¿tiene que ser un array el output?

Comment: No necesariamente, solo quiero que me devuelva una columna con 1 y 0 para cada identificador (NHC) dependiendo si en las columnas [17:36] es decir Código 1 al 20 tengo alguna coincidencia con J45

Comment: Entonces     as.numeric(
      sapply(todo_junto_df[17:36], 
             function(x) any(grep("J45", x)))
      )

Comment: Si pero esta última función solo me dice que columnas tienen J45 a mi me gustaría saber que fila en cada columna tiene esa coincidencia

Comment: @AdriánP.L. sería buena idea que editaras la pregunta indicando que lo que buscas es filtrar: quedarte con ciertas filas. Por convención se usa seleccionar para las operaciones por columnas y filtrar cuando es por filas. Eso haría más clara tu pregunta y podría ayudar a futuro a encontrar la respuesta en casos similares.

Comment: ya he editado la pregunta, creo que ahora es más clara. Muchas gracias por su atención